# How do I get LetsEncrypt working in ASP.Net Core Razor Pages?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, lets-encrypt, razor-pages

How do I get ASP.Net Core Razor Pages to comply with what letsencrypt.com requires for "handshaking?" I had tried using a solution that works with MVC but the way the Route was done didn't work in Razor Pages.

Answer (score 6):

I started with [this excellent tutorial](https://royaljay.com/development/free-ssl-cert-for-azure-web-apps/) from the Royal Jay site. *Adding a Route to the web app* is where my solution diverges from a normal MVC application. Being that you have to get a new SSL certificate every 3 months, I made this solution configurable so that changing the key end up being pretty easy.

In my *appsettings.json* file, I added the following entry for LetsEncrypt:

```
"LetsEncrypt": {
    "Key": "the entire key from your letsencrypt initial session goes here"
  }
```

The entry here is the **entire** key that you receive back from the *letsencrypt-auto* executable (it's the second red-underlined section in the Royal Jay tutorial).

In order to pass the configuration property through to the page that will handle the handshake from LetsEncrypt, I created a new interface and small class that will hold the key:

**Interface:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Main.Interfaces
{
    public interface ILetsEncryptKey
    {
        string GetKey();
    }
}
```

**Class:**

```
using Main.Interfaces;

namespace Main.Models
{
    public class LetsEncryptKey : ILetsEncryptKey
    {
        private readonly string _key;

        public LetsEncryptKey(string key) => _key = key;

        public string GetKey() => _key;
    }
}
```

Then in the *startup.cs* file, I've added these lines into the *ConfigureServices* section:

```
    var letsEncryptInitialKey = Configuration["LetsEncrypt:Key"];

    services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/LetsEncrypt", $".well-known/acme-challenge/{letsEncryptInitialKey.Split('.')[0]}");
    });

    services.AddSingleton<ILetsEncryptKey>(l => new LetsEncryptKey(letsEncryptInitialKey));
```

Now the only thing we have left to do is to create the page that will handle the handshake request and return the response.

**LetsEncrypt.cshtml.cs:**

```
using Main.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace RazorPages.Pages
{
    public class LetsEncryptModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILetsEncryptKey _letsEncryptKey;

        public LetsEncryptModel(ILetsEncryptKey letsEncryptKey)
        {
            _letsEncryptKey = letsEncryptKey;
        }

        public ContentResult OnGet()
        {
            var result = new ContentResult
            {
                ContentType = "text/plain",
                Content = _letsEncryptKey.GetKey()
            };

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i set set it for both www and without www